# Installing Windows safely alongside Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, windows-7

Last time I installed Windows on my from a DVD it was a nightmare. I **NEVER** want to repeat it. There were multiple issues with that. The first one was that it just refused to install itself on the NTFS partition. Neither did formatting option work. So in the end I solved it by wiping the Ubuntu installation and I do not want to do that again.

---

So how can I use virtualbox to boot the DVD and then use the booted installer to install Windows on a partition on the physical hard disk?

I tried adding the NTFS partition (/dev/sda5) as a virtual drive to the virtualbox machine (that booted from the DVD) but it was invisible for the installer for some reason.

Comment: To understand you correctly: You have a UBUNTU-installation on a physical drive and want to install Windows on that drive as well for a dual-boot installation? How does this involve virtualbox? Or do you want to install Windows in a virtualbox environment?

Comment: @HATEthePLOT The first part is correct yes.  The last time I used the DVD installer it caused me a lot of trouble, it refused to install itself on the NTFS partition, neither did the installer manage to format the drive. In the end I had to manually wipe the drive and then Windows agreed to cooperate and install itself.  So this time I want to make sure Windows only has access to that one partition on the physical disk so that it thinks the entire drive is that one partition and it's able to install itself on it.

Comment: That would probably have a worse outcome than just trying to install Windows again, using one of the guides in this site.

Comment: I still don't see how virtualbox may help you here. VB provides a framework for virtualising an OS. You can create a VM and then install Windows in it. But it won't be a dual boot system; you would always have to boot Ubuntu, start virtualbox and fire up the VM.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT I can virtualise the installer, right? So the virtualised installer can somehow write to the physical disk, right?

Comment: Yes, but it will not be able to write the boot sections and will confuse a partition for a full disk. Also it will be installed for the Virtualiced hardware, not the real one and Windows don't usually takes well unexpected hardware changes.

Comment: Is it possible to let it install boot sections? Also, that's about what I want Windows to do, only see that one partition and not mess up others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

virtualbox uses it's own format(s) for their virtual disks, it is not just raw data. It can use a partition to physically write an OS into, but you won't be able to use it without virtualbox.

Comment: It has option for raw disk access. But Windows installer doesn't recognize it as a separate disk for some reason.

Comment: I solved it the way I did before, by nuking the entire drive's content and installing windows on it and then Ubuntu again as Virtualbox was unable to show the installer the drive (I mean, I was unable to tell Virtualbox to show the drive).